# Problemas array con localStorage

Tags: javascript

```
var x2=x1+c;
var x2i=x2.toFixed(2);
var y2=y1+ci;
var y2i=y2.toFixed(2);//52.23
var arrayX2=new Array();
arrayX2.push(y2i);
var arrayX2=new Array();
arrayX2.push(y2i);
```

Al meter el elemento el alert del array me da 1 (CORRECTO)

```
alert(arrayX2.length);

localStorage.setItem(x2i,arrayX2);
```

Ahora viene el problema, al meter el array en la variable del localStorage luego miro el tamaño del array de la variable del localStorage y me da 5, y es como que he metido el numero caracter a caracter como si fuera '5', luego '2' luego '.' luego un '2' y luego un '3' (52.23)

```
alert(localStorage.getItem(x2i).length));
```

He probado a hacer esto:

```
localStorage.setItem(x2i,JSON.stringify(arrayX2));
```

Pero ahora el lenght me da 9;

No se como meter el array correctamente en la variable del localStorage.

Si alguien me puede decir como solucionar esto se lo agradecería.
Un saludo.

Comment: la solucion al localstorage guarde array es llevandolo a string y luego parseandolo a objeto`localStorage.setItem(x2i,JSON.stringify(arrayX2)); `  y luego  `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(x2))`es muy comun a mi me funciona!!

Answer (score 4):

El localStorage no almacena objetos. Si tú pones:

```
var miarray = [1,2,3];
localStorage.setItem('primer_array', miarray);
```

Implícitamente ocurre

```
localStorage.setItem('primer_array', miarray.toString());
```

Que guarda el string `1,2,3`

Por lo mismo, es correcto insertarlo usando `JSON.stringify` como muestras en tu segundo intento:

```
localStorage.setItem(x2i,JSON.stringify(arrayX2));
```

Así que para obtenerlo de vuelta "rehidratado", tienes que recuperarlo como

```
var array_guardado = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(x21));
```

Por otro lado, en tu lógica dices que el elemento que quieres almacenar se define en el snippet

```
var x2=x1+c;
var x2i=x2.toFixed(2);
var y2=y1+ci;
var y2i=y2.toFixed(2);//52.23
var arrayX2=new Array(); // arrayX2 = []
arrayX2.push(y2i); // arrayX2 = ["53.23"]
var arrayX2=new Array(); // arrayX2 = []
arrayX2.push(y2i); // arrayX2 = ["53.23"]
```

Para qué son las dos últimas líneas?

¿Para qué redefines `arrayX2` como un array vacío? Redefinir una variable ya declarada es un antipatrón. Piensa que:

```
var x = 'hola';
console.log(x);
// imprime 'hola';
var x;
console.log(x);
// sigue imprimiento 'hola' cuando debiera imprimir `undefined`
```

¿No será que quieres que el array final contenga `x2i` e `y2i`?Finalmente, no es recomendado usar el constructor de Array `new Array()` sino el literal `[]` para declarar un nuevo array.

Piensa que

`var miarray = []` cuando se interpreta en el motor del browser, llama a `ARRAY_INIT`.

Mientras que `var miarray = new Array()` llama a `new` (constructor) `Array` (identificador) y luego recorre la cadena de prototipos subiendo por el stack hasta llegar a `window.Array`, y sobre ese prototipo llama al método `apply`.

Esto ocurre porque en el camino tú podrías haber añadido métodos al prototipo `Array` (es mala idea, pero se hace) o peor, haber sobreescrito el constructor por ejemplo:

```
Array =  function() {
  this.nombre = 'array';
};
```

Eso generaría que

```
var miaarray = new Array();
```

Fuera un objeto con la propiedad `nombre` y sin métodos como `push`, `shift`, `unshift`, `pop`, etc. Habrías destruído el constructor. Y sin embargo, después de hacer eso

```
var miarray = [];
```

Seguiría intacto y funcionando.

Comment: Por añadir un poco de bibliografía a una buena respuesta: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Answer (score 0):

El problema que veo en tu código es en como usas el "localStorage", comentarte que el "localStorage" y "sessionStorage" solo pueden guardar string, no otro tipo de dato, por lo que no puedes almacenar un "array" directamente, sino tienes que transformarlo en string y a partir de aquí guardarlo. El metodo JSON.stringify() es para JSON no para arrays.

Te muestro un ejemplo:

```
var array = [12.45, 55.55]

//array.toString() => "12.45,55.55"

localStorage.setItem('test',array.toString())

var value = localStorage.getItem('test')

var data = value.split(',')

//data => ["12.45","55.55"]
```

Recuerda transformar los String a Number, en este caso a Float.

Espero que te haya ayudado.

Saludos

Comment: En realidad, cuando usa ".toFixed()" ya se convirtieron en string. Eso me faltó señalar